# Is there a way to add a button to create a bookmark?

Tags: 2013

I want to put a button on a SharePoint page that when the user clicks it, it creates a bookmark (with a specific bookmark NAME) for the page.  I don't know if the answer would be code (java/jQuery?) or not, but I think it is POSSIBLE, I'm just wondering if someone out there knows how to do this?  (Help)​

Just to be clear, I am not looking to add a url to the page, I'm looking for a button that creates a bookmark for the user within the user's "favorites".... would love it if it added it to their favorites bar, too.

Comment: Please have a loot at these threads 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992844/add-to-browser-favorites-bookmarks-from-javascript-but-for-all-browsers-mine-do

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457572/how-to-add-to-favorites-bookmark-for-all-browser-in-javascript

Comment: not sure this link helped... anyone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="button" id="bookmark" value="Bookmark" onclick="ClickFunction()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function ClickFunction() {
      alert("Button Clicked");
      if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel("TITLE",window.location.href);
      } else if(window.external) { // IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite(window.location.href,"TITLE"); 
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: U added this in script editor, and the button appeared. but nothing happened when I clicked on it.

Comment: how would I check

Comment: still didn't do anything\

Comment: I tried this and no go.

Comment: <input type="button" id="bookmark" value="Bookmark" onclick="ClickFunction()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function ClickFunction() {
      if (window.sidebar) { // Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel(JPP!,https://cloudsites.vzbi.com/sites/jppdatabase/Lists/JPP/ER%20Processing.aspx);
      } else if(window.external) { // IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite(URL,TITLE); 
      }
    }
</script>

Comment: Is there a way I can modify this so a button on ONE site creates a bookmark for a DIFFERENT site?  I would love to be able to put a button on the old site so users could create a link to the new site...  but just a button on the NEW site will be extremely helpful!

Comment: do you have a site or a section here for sharepoint tips that you have or gave?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question?